# Generating unique test data with node

Tags: node.js, testing

I'm currently using `chance.js` to generate test data. For example, I can generate a random email and use it to test my models.

My problem is that I need to ensure some fields on my models are unique e.g. email on the user model. Does `chance` ensure that it doesn't generate the same email twice?

I'd be willing to use `faker` as an alternative but I couldn't find out if `faker` offered this functionality.

Comment: generate the entire set of test data before running tests and check for duplicates yourself? or use a counter and sequential strings? also this is a bad question without posting the code you want to improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a unique function at `chance.js` which also support comparator functionality From the change.js docs :

> The comparator used to determine whether a generated item is in the
>   list of already generated items. By default the comparator just checks
>   to see if the newly generated item is in the array of already
>   generated items. This works for most simple cases (such as
>   chance.state()) but will not work if the generated item is an object
>   (because the Array.prototype.indexOf() method will not work on an
>   object since 2 objects will not be strictly equal, ===, unless they
>   are references to the same object).

```
chance.unique(chance.currency, 2, {
    comparator: function(err, val) {
        return arr.reduce(function(acc, item) {
            return acc || (item.code === val.code);
        }, false);
    }
});
```

check the [docs](http://chancejs.com/#unique)  for more details...